# Use Android Speech Recognition so that it stops only at the press of a button

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I want to use speech recognition to record until you press the stop button .
Do you know any way to do this?

I tried a solution but it only works as long as you do not take breaks too long(4-5s).
If you press the STOP button when it stops then starts again to work...

How can I correct it?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.STT);

    intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizer = SpeechRecognizer
            .createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
    recognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);

}

public void start(View view) {
    recognizer.startListening(intent);
}

public void stop(View view) {
    recognizer.stopListening();
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle res) {

    ArrayList<String> results = res
            .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

    myText.setText(results.get(0));
    // ...

    recognizer.startListening(intent);

}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    //...
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    //...
}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle data) {
    //...
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
    //...
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {
    //...
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    //...
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    //...
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice Recognition stops listening after a few seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670378/voice-recognition-stops-listening-after-a-few-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

This is a JB problem maybe by design. For a work around you can implement the voice recognition in a service and then send update to your UI based on the results. For an implementation of service work around see  [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616)