# How to increase recording time/length using RecognizerIntent

Tags: android, speech-recognition, recognizer-intent

I am working on application in which i am using RecognizerIntent for speech to text conversion. At the moment i am able to record audio for 15 seconds only. i have been searching a lot for this issue but couldn't found anything. I also tried to make use of the various available RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT parameters but they have no effect.

Can anyone help me on this issue please?

Comment: have you use this EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS tag

Comment: This no longer works in more recent versions of the Google Search application (which controls elements of the API) http://stackoverflow.com/a/19556265/1256219

Comment: yes i use EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, but it did not make any difference.