# Changing Timeout for Receiving Voice Input

Tags: android, speech-recognition, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I develop an android app, that sends a notification to the connected android wear smartwatch. This notification contains the possibility to replay by voice input. The spoken message is shown on the handheld as a toast (for testing). The user has to click a button, which belongs to the notification. On click the Google voice record starts and works well.

The problem is, that the message of the user can be long and containing breaks for some seconds. Is there a possibility to increase the timeout? So android wear records for x seconds no spoken word before stopping recording?

Or is it more practical to record the speech via a button "start recording" and "stop recording" and use after that the "Google-speech-to-text-service"?

My Notification code bases on this [tutorial](https://github.com/LarkspurCA/androidweardocs/blob/master/demand.rst).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice Recognition stops listening after a few seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670378/voice-recognition-stops-listening-after-a-few-seconds)

Comment: The question above isn't a duplicate with my question. The problem isn't a dying service. I want to increase the time android wear is waiting for other spoken words. Your answer forwarded me to EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS. This attribute seems to be what I'm looking for. 

But it doesn't work. Nothing changes when I add it.
`.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILL‌​IS, new Long(5000));`