# How to check SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I develop an app, when my speech recognizer work very well. The problem is that when pass 25 minutes, the speech recognizer don't run and don't throw any error.

I need that the speech recognizer work indefinitely, for this I create a Service tu check every 5 minutes the status of speech recognizer but it don't work correctly.

What is the best form to check the status of speech recognizer?

Thanks and wait your responses

Comment: You means, you want to run your SpeechRecognizer in background?

Comment: try using long running service.

Comment: @AshishJohn Long running Service???

Comment: @iSandeep No the app is always in foreground, but when pass 25-30 minutes the speech recognizer don't work

Comment: Have you read this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670378/voice-recognition-stops-listening-after-a-few-seconds

Comment: If your application is running in foreground, then why don't you trigger SpeechRecognizer on any event like Button click?

Comment: @AshishJohn yes I read this, but not is my problem, The speech recognizer work correctly for 25-30 minutes

Comment: @iSandeep It is a system of continuous listening, I can not put a button that activates it at a certain time, since it would lose all its functionality

Comment: SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this);

Comment: @AshishJohn this function, "Checks whether a speech recognition service is available on the system. If this method returns false, createSpeechRecognizer(Context) will fail."